# “And to the many of you, William.”

Tags: grammar, irregular-plurals

I was taken aback by this phrase directed at me in response to my “Merry Christmas”.

> And to the many of you, William.

Is it in any way correct?

Perhaps it is Old English, or a quote from a period play of Shakespeare... I am perplexed, as there is only one of me!

Comment: What do you object to in the phrase? It seems fine as a reference to perhaps a large family, cohort or class, etc.

Comment: I say Merry Christmas to the many of you = your family.

Comment: This is not at all idiomatic to me (an Australian English speaker), and I would share your confusion if someone said this to me. I am absolutely fascinated to find the above comments treating it as quite normal! We truly are separated by a common language.

Comment: @TimPederick ditto from me (UK). Only circumstances I can imagine someone saying that would be if you were in a group at the time of the greeting and they meant to include all in the greeting. Even then the phrasing would be weird to me.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I can find reputable sources for this, but in religious contexts, *many* can be used with the meaning of ***all***. For example, in the verse:

> The Son of man came not to be ministered unto, but to minister, and to give his life a ransom for ***many***. (Matt. 20:28 KJV)

it makes sense to read it as meaning

> a ransom for ***all***.

The same with

> For ***many*** are called, but few are chosen. (Matt. 22:14 KJV)

So, I would understand the wish you received as meaning:

> And to all of you.

It is true, the way it is written, this wish is quirky and has a dated turn to it. It is elegant and aims to give it a festal atmosphere, different from a mere informal, casual answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is no more in this "many of you" than an allusion à la Walt Whitman who could write in one of his poetries "(I am large, I contain multitudes.)".

[Song of Myself    
Walt Whitman - 1819-1892](https://poets.org/poem/song-myself-51)